# Filling a multidimensional array using loops (NetBeans IDE 8.2)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, netbeans-8

I'm trying to fill two 2 by 2 arrays, one being a String, the other an integer.

```
package javaapplication24;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Joshua
 */
public class JavaApplication24 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String[][] arrString;
arrString = new String[2][2];
int[][] arrInt;
arrInt = new int[2][2];
for(int a = 1; a != 3; a++){
for(int b = 1; b != 3; b++){
System.out.println ("Enter a \"String\" for " +a+ " - " +b+ ".");
arrString[a][b] = sc.next();
}}
for(int a = 1; a != 3; a++){
for(int b = 1; b != 3; b++){
System.out.println ("Enter a \"Integer\" for " +a+ " - " +b+ ".");
arrInt[a][b] = sc.nextInt();  
}}
System.out.println (arrString[1][1] = arrString[1][2] + arrString[2][1] + arrString[2][2]);
System.out.println (arrInt[1][1] + arrInt[1][2] + arrInt [2][1] + arrInt[2][2]);
}}
```

Every single time that I try to change something with the loops it seems to only go to 1 - 2 and then gives me a error on line 28.

I have no clue what else I could do to fill the rest of the array slots.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Indices are 0-based meaning your loops should look like this:
for (int a=0;a<2;a++)  -  The same with accessing -> The first entry is [0][0] etc.

Comment: GrafWampula. That helped so much! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last lines from this:

```
System.out.println (arrString[1][1] = arrString[1][2] + arrString[2][1] + arrString[2][2]);
System.out.println (arrInt[1][1] + arrInt[1][2] + arrInt [2][1] + arrInt[2][2]);
```

to this:

```
System.out.println (arrString[0][0] = arrString[0][1] + arrString[1][0] + arrString[1][1]);
System.out.println (arrInt[0][0] + arrInt[0][1] + arrInt [1][0] + arrInt[1][1]);
```

Arrays indexes start from 0 and both matrix lengths are 2 so the indexes for both matrix will be:
00,01,10,11